# Calling `reversed` on a list vs another iterator (such as tuple) results in different output

Tags: python, list, tuples, iterable

Call `reversed` on a list:

```
>>> reversed([1, 2, 3])
<list_reverseiterator object at 0x102a84908>
```

Now, call it on another iterable..., say a tuple:

```
>>> reversed((1, 2, 3))
<reversed object at 0x102a848d0>
```

The first bit of code yields a `list_reverseiterator object` while the second yields `reversed object`.

Similar behaviour observed across all pythons. **So, why is there a difference?**

From the docs,

> Return a reverse iterator. seq must be an object which has a
>   `__reversed__()` method or supports the sequence protocol (the `__len__()` method and the `__getitem__()` method with integer arguments starting at
>   0).

Does this have something to do with whether `__reversed__` is implemented or not? Because...

```
>>> list.__reversed__
<method '__reversed__' of 'list' objects>
```

But

```
>>> tuple.__reversed__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'tuple' has no attribute '__reversed__'
```

Comment: If that duplicate doesn't answer what you're trying to get at just let me know.

Comment: @Mitch It should.. thanks :)